# gzip compression does not work for all files

Tags: javascript, apache, .htaccess, gzip

I configured htaccess file to active gzip compression on my website. This is my config:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule filter_module>
    FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/html
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/css
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/plain
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $text/x-component
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/javascript
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/json
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/xhtml+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/rss+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/atom+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $image/svg+xml
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $application/x-font-ttf
    FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE resp=Content-Type $font/opentype
    FilterChain     COMPRESS
    FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Gzip compression works well on all files of my website, except one of them. The file that is not compressed is a json file with js format (map.js) and its size is about 3MB.

Request Headers:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fa;q=0.6
AlexaToolbar-ALX_NS_PH:AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.3
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=lr9h0qmqcmaidakagt34385rn3
Host:aqcc.chetoriha.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://aqcc.chetoriha.com/mapview.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 15:19:57 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
ETag: "2ac47b-552d59e8-837e4d9f058b5c4c"
Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Apr 2015 18:18:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 2802811
Cache-Control: public
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Expires: Wed, 13 Apr 2016 15:19:57 GMT
```

Why all files are compressed well but map.js is not compressed???

Comment: What content-type does it ship as? (This is independent of the file extension; you can look it up in the browser developer tools or using `wget --server-response` or th elike..)

Comment: content-type is application/javascript

Comment: Have you ever figured out why it did not encode?